# Decrypt rijndael-128 String with PHP OpenSSL return empty

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I want to decrypt a string using rijdael-128 with ECB method.

Here is the code that encrypts a string in C#:

```
static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key){
    string cipherText;
    var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged()
    {
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key),
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros, 
    };
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.key, null);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(plaintext);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

and I want to decrypt the encrypted string generated using the above function with OpenSSL in PHP:

```
function decrypt($text,$key){
    $encrypted = base64_decode($text);

        $decrypted = rtrim(openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'AES-256-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING),"\0");

    
    return $decrypted;
}
```

But it returns an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least one bug is that Zero padding is used in the C# code, while  in the PHP code PKCS7 padding is implicitly applied. If possible you should switch to PKCS7 padding in the C# code (which is the default), as it is more reliable than Zero padding. ECB is insecure by the way, better use a mode with an IV, e.g. GCM.

Comment: @Topaco i have no access to the C code. also changed my option to OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING but to no avail

Comment: Then you have to disable the PKCS7 padding in the PHP code with `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` (i.e. here `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`) and remove the padding _manually_ from the decrypted data, e.g. with `rtrim(decrypted, "\0")`.

Comment: @Topaco thankyou! now i get an empty string! have any idea why?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://paiza.io/projects/KGQW2dft1KpA02nbZlMuSw), where the ciphertext was generated with your C# code with the plaintext _The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog_ and the key _0123456789012345_.

Comment: @Topaco thankyou verymuch, i think the C admin sent me a wrong key to test with, it longer than 16 characters

Comment: AES supports 16/24/32 bytes keys corresponding to the variants AES-128/192/256. C# determines the variant from the key length, in the PHP code it must be _explicitly_ specified, e.g. `aes-256-ecb` for a 32 bytes key (note that PHP shortens or lengthens the key depending on the specification).

Comment: Is the issue solved, because I can't reproduce it even for AES-256/32 bytes keys, see [C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/prHpGc), [PHP](https://paiza.io/projects/lKktZv7AqdGKAcgmnOdu1w)?

Comment: @Topaco yes de issue is solved, i hadn't recieved the right key from the C admin, thank you again for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @Topaco this was the key i got from the C admin: "2b8958eb1da990c039933a504259059fc9c8a893447fcbb3a8c504797e637278" which is more than 16 characters