# how to use openssl_decrypt using hex as key?

Tags: c#, php, encryption

i want to decrypt an encrypted string using openssl in PHP,

the string is encrypted in C# using this code:

```
    private static MemoryStream MsEncrypt = null;
    private static CryptoStream CsEncrypt = null;
    public static string EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key)
    {
        using (var rijndaelConfig = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndaelConfig.Key = key;
            rijndaelConfig.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelConfig.BlockSize = 128;
            rijndaelConfig.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijndaelConfig.GenerateIV();
            
            var encryptor = rijndaelConfig.CreateEncryptor(rijndaelConfig.Key,
                                                           rijndaelConfig.IV);
            byte[] encrypted;
            try
            {
                MsEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
                CsEncrypt = new CryptoStream(MsEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(CsEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.AutoFlush = true;
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = MsEncrypt.ToArray();
                byte[] result = new byte[rijndaelConfig.IV.Length + encrypted.Length];
                rijndaelConfig.IV.CopyTo(result, 0);
                encrypted.CopyTo(result, rijndaelConfig.IV.Length);
                return Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(result));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (MsEncrypt != null)
                {
                    MsEncrypt.Dispose();
                }
                if (CsEncrypt != null)
                {
                    CsEncrypt.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my key: "2b8958eb1da990c039933a504259059fc9c8a893447fcbb3a8c504797e637288"
and this is my string: "hello[[]]there!"
and this is the encrypted value "O0wTQerC%2FQs5sFUMc3uXoSkrsJcY7toWqlsQYRYAD64%3D"
here is a working encrypt and decrypt function in fiddle (C#): https://dotnetfiddle.net/9BKh5J

this is what ive tried so far in php to encrypt this:

```
function decrypt($text,$key){
    $encrypted = base64_decode($text);
    $key = unpack('C*', $key);

    $key = implode('',$key);

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING );
    return rtrim($decrypted, "\0");
}
```

here is the php fiddle: https://paiza.io/projects/zwXd611Gw5snUclFMjebEw

but i get an empty string, any idea why?

Comment: You have already asked a similar question under another account [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66596540/9014097). You can hex decode the key with `hex2bin()`, but you have to apply `aes-256-cbc` for a 32 bytes key. Before the Base64 decoding of the data, `$text` has to be URL decoded with `urldecode()`. Also, IV and ciphertext must be separated with `substr()` (the first 16 bytes are the IV, the rest is the ciphertext) and of course the IV must be used in [`openssl_decrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) (passed as 5th parameter).

Comment: @Topaco yes but my other acocunt couldnt post another question, thats why i made this, i have changed the fiddle am i on the right direction?

Comment: @Topaco im nearly there, i see my string, but how do i seperate the IV from my text?

Comment: @Topaco nvm im stupid, you answered it already

Comment: @Topaco thankyou very very much